# Nuxt js 3 scroll behavior after page load completed

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

`router.options.js` file:

```js
export default {
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    return {
      top: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    }
  },
}
```

I'm using `useAsyncData` in the page I'm navigating to. So there's a delay between page navigations, because the router waits for the data fetch. The problem is the page is scrolled immediately and not waiting for the new page render to start. So I'm at the old page having the scrollbar going to the top before the new page to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it with the following code:

```
export default {
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      nuxtApp.hooks.hookOnce('page:finish', () => {
        resolve({
          top: 0,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        })
      })
    })
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.This works on chrome but on firefox it's not working.

Comment: @lwinmoehein Try to update nuxt to the latest version

Answer (score 2):

It's better not to call `nuxtApp.hook` in `scrollBehavior`

`scrollBehavior` is called every time the page is changed.

`nuxtApp.hook('page:finish')` will create a new hook (which needs to be manually unregistered before `scrollBehavior` is done) every time a navigation is complete.

It's better to use `hookOnce` instead, as suggested [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/17720#discussioncomment-2415959)

```
// app/router.options.ts

export default <RouterOptions>{
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
   
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      nuxtApp.hooks.hookOnce('page:finish', async () => {
        await nextTick()
        resolve(position)
   }
}
```